# why I unable to generate the rspec files while scaffold with rails 2.3.* version?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, rspec1

I have tried to generate spec related files also while doing scaffold.

As normally, it will generate spec files along with all other CRUD related files while doing
scaffold.

But here, I trying with Rails 2.3.18 version + rspec, rspec-rails 1.3.2,1.3.4

Its not creating the spec files in spec folder but creating in test folder.

How I can achieve it?

Any Ideas? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, script/generate rspec_scaffold Model_Name